# Dynamic keyword does not work with IoC but classic reflection does

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have made a little CQRS API for our system
I tried to replace some reflection code by using the dynamic keyword but it does not work

Each command handler is Generic `CommandHandler<TCommand>` with a Method `void Execute(TCommand Command)`

With reflection it works

```
public void Invoke(Contracts.Commands.Command command)
{
    var handlerType = types[command.GetType()];

    var handler = kernel.Get(handlerType);
    var method = handlerType.GetMethod("Execute");
    method.Invoke(handler, new object[] { command });
}
```

`Kernel.Get` is the untyped version of `kernel.Get<T>` in our IoC (Ninject). This works and the generic method Execute of T fires

This code fails with a argument mismatch exception

```
public void Invoke(Contracts.Commands.Command command)
{
    var handlerType = types[command.GetType()];

    dynamic handler = kernel.Get(handlerType);
    handler.Execute(command);
}
```

If i statically declare the type it works with dynamic

```
dynamic handler = new TestCommandHandler();
handler.Execute(new TestCommand());
```

**edit:** Some more info to answer questions in comments

- handlerType is a concrete class that implements the abstract class `CommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : Command`
- The execute method is declared in the abstract class as `public virtual void Execute(TCommand command)`
- TestCommand implements the abstract Class Command
- Strange thing is that the same Handler and command works if I statically declare them strongly typed, last example (In the real world example I have dependencies in the constructor though

  **edit2**
- Stacktrace

> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Command )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    at
>   XXX.Business.Command.CommandHandlerInvoker.Invoke(Command
>   command) in
>   C:\XXX.Business\Command\CommandHandlerInvoker.cs:line
>   29    at XXX.Web.XXXService.Execute(Command command) in
>   C:\XXX.Web\ExfiService.svc.cs:line 29    at
>   XXX.Web.Controllers.ComplianceController.XXX(XXXViewModel
>   viewModel) in
>   C:\XXX.Web\Controllers\XXXController.cs:line
>   52    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

- Exception

> The best overloaded method match for
>   `XXX.Business.Command.CommandHandler<XXX.Contracts.Commands.TestCommand>.Execute(XXX.Contracts.Commands.TestCommand)' has some invalid arguments`

**Error message is stating the abstract class of T not the concrete class, but handlerType in above code is the concrete class**

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace of your exception.

Comment: Is the `handlerType` an interface? a concrete class? an abstract class? And is `Execute` public? internal? protected? an explicit-interface-implementation? or...? Likewise, `Command` and `TestCommand`? most of the subtleties with `dynamic` revolve around a: accessibility, and b: interfaces vs public API

Comment: Here's sample code that fails to reproduce your problem: https://gist.github.com/3987010 . I'd check the binding is correct, and that `Execute` has the argument you think it has.

Comment: I can reproduce this error, but only when `CommandHandler<T>.Execut(T)` gets an argument that is not of type `T` - in your case, if the generic type of `handler` is not the same as the type of `command`.

Comment: Just a quick debug - Maybe you can try looking at `command.GetType().Name` and `handler.GetType().Name`? Make sure `handler` is of type `TestCommandHandler`, and not `CommandHandler<TCommand>` (though, it should work... I still cannot reproduce it)

Comment: Yupp, its the correct concrete type, but the error message says the abstract class for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your code to look like this:

```
public void Invoke(Contracts.Commands.Command command)
{
    var handlerType = types[command.GetType()];

    dynamic handler = kernel.Get(handlerType);
    dynamic cmd = command;
    handler.Execute(cmd);
}
```

Notice that the `command` parameter is first assigned to a dynamic local variable (`cmd`). This allows the type of `cmd` to be evaluated at runtime and keeps the call to `Execute` truly dynamic; where as NOT doing it this way, the `Execute` method is assumed to have a fixed signature of `Execute(Contracts.Commands.Command command)`

Comment: Haha, I feel like an idiot that I didn't think about trying that! :P Thanks!